# Why does $f(xy) = f(x)+ f(y) \implies f(x) = k \ln x$

Tags: functions, logarithms

My textbook says $f(xy) = f(x)+ f(y) \implies f(x) = k \ln x$

But if I'm not mistaken, $f(x)$ could be a logarithmic function with any base? So why only $\ln x$?

Comment: From the change of basis formula for logarithms we have $\log_{b}x=\dfrac{\ln x}{\ln b}$ where $b>0$ and $b\neq 1$.

Comment: I think it's a general term. After all it says $k ln x$, with $k$ being some constant. Since it is possible to convert logarithm bases through multiplying by a constant, you can get any base you want.

Comment: @P.Diddy Thank you, I understand now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\log_ax=\frac1{\ln a}\ln x$. So, a generic logarithmic function is always a multiple of the natural logarithm.

Note that I am *not* asserting that these are the only solutions. What I am saying is that the multiples of the natural logarithm contain the logarithms in arbitrary bases.

Comment: Thank you my good sir!

Answer (score 8):

This is false. If we let $g(x)=f(e^x),$ then we find that $g$ satisfies Cauchy's functional equation, and hence there are infinitely many pathological $g$ which correspond to solutions $f=g(\ln x).$ You must place some continuity or differentiability restrictions on $f.$